# Android app Locale changed programatically but NotificationCompact shows message in Device language

Tags: android

I have an App which support 4 languages. I allow the user to choose from this language and I change the language with this code:

```
    Locale locale_en = new Locale(locale);
    Locale.setDefault(locale_en);
    Configuration config_en = new Configuration();
    config_en.locale = locale_en;
    getBaseContext().getResources()
            .updateConfiguration(config_en, getBaseContext()
                    .getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    recreate();
```

Also, each day I pop up a reminder (using the `AlarmManager`) with the `NotificationCompat` class with this code:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NavigationActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_v2)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_text))
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    int mNotificationId = 001;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

**THE PROBLEM IS**: that the Notification appears not in the language that the user choose **from my App** but it appears in the language of the device.
I'm able to use the app in different languages but the notification always appears in the Device Language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, each day I pop up a reminder (using the AlarmManager) with the NotificationCompat class with this code:

Your process will have long since been terminated, so this code is running in a fresh process. You will need to apply your same update-the-`Locale` logic here as well as when the user chooses a language in your UI.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare! it works!. I save in my sharedPreference the locale selected and in the Broadcast receiver I use the same Locale logic.